# How to delete a custom data type in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have created a datatype in PostgreSQL using folloing line:

```
CREATE TYPE ABC AS (A CHARACTER(1), B CHARACTER(2), C BIGINT);
```

I didn't define this datatype. Now I want to delete this prototype. 
What is the way or command to delete this?

Comment: This is not a function. It's a data type. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createtype.html

Comment: @ConsiderMe: Thanks for correction. I changed it to datatype.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can remove a data type using

```
DROP TYPE type_name;
```

[Click here for manual reference for DROP TYPE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-droptype.html)

Remember, that if you have other objects that depend on the type you are trying to delete, it would yield an error

```
ERROR:  cannot drop type type_name because other objects depend on it
```

with list of dependencies.

If you would also like to `DROP` those objects type

```
DROP TYPE type_name CASCADE;
```

Comment: Thanks for solution with explanation :)

Comment: Does this mean one should e.g. update all columns first and alter their type into a varchar (or digit) ?

Comment: @Rom's if your intention is not to drop columns, then yes. First alter tables to change column data type, then drop your custom type.

Answer (score 4):

Try remove this `TYPE`  this way

```
DROP TYPE ABC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the schema name first

```
DROP TYPE schema_name.type_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Note:

Ensure to put quotes in type name to correctly search on database, otherwise it will throw that doesn't exist.

Example:

```
DROP TYPE "NameOfType" CASCADE;
```